# Pytest: Returning a value on the method command of a mocked item

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

python 3.6

I'm trying to set the output of a mocked item to a string, but am running into errors. Normally the idea is that you use `mock.return_value` or `mock.side_effect` but that's not working for me here:

Script

```
def main():
    config = Config(config_env) 
    print('the config ',config)
    table = config.get(config_key,"table")
    print(table)
```

Test

```
class TestMain:

    @patch('path.Config')
    def test_main_success(self, config_mock):
        main()
```

When I run the test, the first output is `the config < MagicMock name='Config()' id='123123'>` Great. Now , I want to be able to have the output of `config.get(...)` to be a string.

```
config_mock.return_value = 'my string'
```

fails because it converts the value `config` to a string and you can't put `.get` on a string. Next I try

```
config_mock.get.return_value = 'my string'
```

however, this too fails. The output is `< MagicMock name='Config()' id='567567'>` which is a different id than before, but it should have been `my string`.

What's the correct way to return a specific output for `config.get(...)`

Comment: `config_mock.return_value.get.return_value = 'my string'`

Comment: oh... that makes so much sense. thank you! I didn't realize that you had to chain it like that

Comment: Happy to help! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Complementing [hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650249/hoefling) comment you could use, also, a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide) and define all properties of mock on it's call.

```
def test_main_success(self):
    with patch('path.Config.get', return_value="my string")a as config_mock:
        main()
```